# What does auto always deduce the basic type mean here

Tags: c++11

I was reading [this](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/13/gotw-93-solution-auto-variables-part-2/) article which states

that

```
widget w = get_gadget(); -->a
auto w = get_gadget();   -->b
```

in statement 'a' a temporary is created then widget w is move constructed from the temporary. I totally understand that statement. What I don't understand is how statement 'b' using the `auto` variable is better than statement 'a'. It says

> .... we could write the following which guarantees there is no
>   implicit conversion because auto always deduces the basic type
>   exactly:
>
> // better, if you don't need an explicit type
>
> `auto w = get_gadget();`

Could anyone please explain why statement 'b' is better than 'a' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what your criteria are for "better".

If the return type of `get_gadget()` is actually `widget`, and that will forever be true, then there is no difference whatsoever.   However, real-world program designs change, and there may be a need to change the return type, or change properties of the type returned.

If the return type of `get_gadget()` is something (say `gadget`) that can be implicitly converted to `widget`, then the working of "a" is effectively

```
gadget temp = get_gadget();
widget w = widget(temp);    //   assuming widget has a constructor that accepts a gadget
```

or to

```
gadget temp = get_gadget();
widget w = (gadget)widget;    //   assuming gadget has an implicit conversion to widget
```

In either case, a temporary object is created and then some conversion is performed.

In comparison, the case "b" is deduced by the compiler as being

```
gadget w = get_gadget();
```

There is also potentially a maintenance advantage in using `auto`.   Let's say that our return type from `get_gadget()` (`gadget`) is changed so it can no longer be converted to a `widget`.   In that case, the case "a" will simply not compile.   Whereas case "b" will compile, and the code which uses `w` will still work (assuming all operations on it are supported by the new return type).

While that last case could easily be fixed by changing to

```
gadget w = get_gadget();
```

even this can be broken again by changing the return type of `get_gadget()` to `better_gadget`.

The bottom line is that `auto` hands the work to the compiler of worrying about what type `w` needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

Sutter explains it in the paragraph.

> This works, assuming that gadget is implicitly convertible to widget, but creates a temporary object. That’s a potential performance pitfall, as the creation of the temporary object is not at all obvious from reading the call site alone in a code review. If we can use a gadget just as well as a widget in this calling code and so don’t explicitly need to commit to the widget type, we could write the following which guarantees there is no implicit conversion because auto always deduces the basic type exactly

Statement b creates a `gadget` directly. That bypasses the creation of the temporary and the conversion, which could be expensive operations depending on the class implementation. `auto` picks the exact type needed and directly creates `w` as that type. His caveat is important though: the code can't care that `w` is a `gadget` and not a `widget`.

For example, suppose that `widget` inherits from `gadget`. In statement b `w` would be a plain `gadget`, thus lacking the extra stuff that you'd get with a `widget`. When using statement b your code can't care that you got a `gadget`. If you're using statement `a` then you get the `widget` at the added expense of creating a temporary `gadget` and converting it to a `widget`.